# Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1: Error while building project

Tags: android, android-studio

I just recently upgraded from Arctic Fox to Dolphin and migrated my project from Gradle 7.0.3 to 7.3.0.

When I want to build project I got error:

```
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0)
```

My entire project is non-usable and broken right now.

Comment: If you are using kotlin , you should only use extensions library provided by android for viewmodels, activities, fragments as such. 

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened with me when I added the `androidx.preference.preference-ktx:1.2.0`
dependency in gradle.

Just add this dependency in `build.gradle` file to fix this.

**Java ->**
`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1'`

**Kotlin ->**
`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'`

This error occurs due to one of the dependencies having an explicit dependency of lifecycle `2.3.1`.

Google Tracker Issue Link -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242384116

Hope this helps :)